# Working with DateTime picker

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I am making an app in which user select the time and than I convert time into string using this code.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    NSString * dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timePicker.date];
```

and than I save the dateTimeString in coreData. Now I want to that "datetimestring" again converted into picker form like that 
[image]

how can I achieve that?? Is there a way to convert the time string into a picker form??

Comment: In my assumption you got the output , but need only thing , you want to pass the `dateTimeString` to coredata correct

Comment: Rather converting into `NSString` for Core data storage, you can directly store `NSDate` format. So while fetching you will get the exact same object.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Thanks a lit @Mrunal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `dateFromString` of a similar `NSDateFormatter` instance.

By the way, you can store instances of `NSDate` in Core Data directly.